# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Can't create PendingServiceRouting object because the status of the work item is completed.: WorkItem ID

Tags: visual-workflow, omnichannel, slack

I am not able to figure out what condition handles this error.

A flow that creates PSR records, and input workItemId is newly created Swarm Member record Id (just before this create record node) and its status is obviously not completed.

Please advise! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Mine is for a Case with a custom status. I'm unable to find anything in the code or online to indicate what is being run/triggered to determine that the case is "completed".

Comment: Changing the Case records to have a Status of "Open" or "New" before attempting to create the PSR does not change this behavior.

Comment: @chadgh Looks like given workItemId's status was not caused this problem.
relieved that someone also has been facing this issue. There is no information about this online.

Comment: @mkzyk I created a test flow to check this out. I am able to create the PSR records without any error. The work item I used is Case (which I am creating 2 nodes before Create PSR node). Can you share some more details around how the flow gets triggered and a screenshot of all the nodes would help and the screenshot of the node where you are creating the swarm record. Thanks !

Comment: Still getting error by setting up Swarming on developer edition.
Please follow this step and use this flow.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.set_up_swarming.htm&type=5

Comment: I ended up getting this solved. I had the Service Channel associated with the PSRs using a different custom status field. I switched it to use the default Status field and was able to get it working.

Comment: Hi @chadgh, are you working on Swarming as well?
I disabled "Enable Status-Based Capacity Model" on omni-channel settings make this error gone, however still routing is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is status field on Swarm Member object, API name of each status value was Japanese, that's the cause of error. Because system can not recognize those values.
If you encounter this error, make sure status API name of related object is in English.